# Why is the "eilah" tree so special?

Tags: vayishlach, shoftim--book-of, trees, masechet-yevamot

After the battle for Dinah, Yaakov Avinu tells those with him to bury their idols under the "eilah" tree.

> **[Bereishis (35:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.35.4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)** -  וַיִּתְּנוּ אֶל־יַעֲקֹב אֵת כָּל־אֱלֹהֵי הַנֵּכָר אֲשֶׁר בְּיָדָם וְאֶת־הַנְּזָמִים אֲשֶׁר בְּאָזְנֵיהֶם
> וַיִּטְמֹן אֹתָם יַעֲקֹב תַּחַת הָאֵלָה אֲשֶׁר עִם־שְׁכֶם -  They gave
> to Jacob all the alien gods that they had, and the rings that were in
> their ears, and Jacob buried them under the "eilah" tree that was near
> Shechem.

Before appointing Gidon as a leader, Hashem sends an angel to the "eilah" tree.

> [**Shoftim (6:11)**](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.6.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) - וַיָּבֹא מַלְאַךְ יְהוָה וַיֵּשֶׁב תַּחַת
> הָאֵלָה אֲשֶׁר בְּעָפְרָה אֲשֶׁר לְיוֹאָשׁ אֲבִי הָעֶזְרִי וְגִדְעוֹן
> בְּנוֹ חֹבֵט חִטִּים בַּגַּת לְהָנִיס מִפְּנֵי מִדְיָן -  An angel of
> GOD came and sat under the "eilah" tree at Ophrah, which belonged to
> Joash the Abiezrite. His son Gideon was then beating out wheat inside
> a winepress in order to keep it safe from the Midianites.

**[Mishna Yevamos (12:6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yevamot.12.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)** - After Rav Elazar Hyrnakus taught a new method of chalitzah under the "eilah" tree, the Rabanan confirmed his new idea.

> וּכְשֶׁהִקְרָא רַבִּי הֻרְקְנוֹס תַּחַת הָאֵלָה בִּכְפַר עֵיטָם
> וְגָמַר אֶת כָּל הַפָּרָשָׁה, הֻחְזְקוּ לִהְיוֹת גּוֹמְרִין כָּל
> הַפָּרָשָׁה -  And when Rabbi Hyrkanus once prompted the participants
> in ḥalitza under the "eilah" tree in the village of Eitam, he prompted
> them to finish reciting the whole Torah passage, after which they
> established the custom of completing the whole Torah passage.
> Therefore, they continue and say the following verse: “And his name
> shall be called in Israel: The house of he who had his shoe removed”
> (Deuteronomy 25:10).

What is so special about this "eilah" tree?

Comment: Who translates אלה as elm?

Comment: Other tree types are mentioned too in different places. I don't think cherry picking three examples of this species proves it's special in any way

Comment: What's so special about cherries?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the fact that Tanach goes out of the way to describe the species of the tree means it's significant. Not one letter in Tanach is superfluous.

Comment: Part of it may simply have been to help future generations identify the location ...

Comment: Perhaps it was physically distinctive?

Comment: It's a big name in Kabbalah. Think about it, isn't it ELW"H the singular of Elohi"m, written chasser.

Comment: There are many ancient civilisations in which elms held special significance.